# angular js dropdown default value

Tags: javascript, android, html, angularjs

So in the following script how can we set ''CAR1'' as default value to our dropdown list??
many thanks in advance

```js
</script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>Select a car:</p>

<select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="x for (x, y) in cars">
</select>

<h1>You selected: {{selectedCar.brand}}</h1>
<h2>Model: {{selectedCar.model}}</h2>
<h3>Color: {{selectedCar.color}}</h3>

<p>Note that the selected value represents an object.</p>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cars = {
        car01 : {brand : "Ford", model : "Mustang", color : "red"},
        car02 : {brand : "Fiat", model : "500", color : "white"},
        car03 : {brand : "Volvo", model : "XC90", color : "black"}
    }
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select ng-init="selectedCar = cars.car01" ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="x for (x, y) in cars">
</select>
```

use `ng-init` and assign the default value to the `ng-model` variable `selectedCar`

Answer (score 1):

Set you default value after assigning the options. Set default value like this `$scope.selectedCar = $scope.cars.car01;`. I have also updated the code.

```js
</script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>Select a car:</p>

<select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="x for (x, y) in cars">
</select> 
 

<h1>You selected: {{selectedCar.brand}}</h1>
<h2>Model: {{selectedCar.model}}</h2>
<h3>Color: {{selectedCar.color}}</h3>

<p>Note that the selected value represents an object.</p>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cars = {
        car01 : {brand : "Ford", model : "Mustang", color : "red"},
        car02 : {brand : "Fiat", model : "500", color : "white"},
        car03 : {brand : "Volvo", model : "XC90", color : "black"}
    }
    
    $scope.selectedCar = $scope.cars.car01; // set here
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
```